# How to use static in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have one static shared resource in multi-threaded environment.So, What are the things i need to consider for multi-threaded environment in order to ensure sequential access?

Comment: proper synchronization, or immutability. With some code, we could be more specific.

Comment: You need to synchronize read and write access to this ressource. For this you need a lock which is shared among all threads using this ressource.

Comment: Perform operations on it using Class level lock.

Comment: So, Probably this is one of the preferred way of better multi-threading experience. Am i right?

Answer (score 3):

Perform operations on it using Class level lock. For e.g.

```
public static void setResource(someResource) {
     synchronized(ClassName.class) {
          resource = someResource;
     }
}
```

alternately you can do the following

```
public static synchronized void setResource(someResource) {
          resource = someResource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if its a ReadOnly Resource try to make it immutable then you need not worry about 
multithreading.

if its not ReadOnly then try don't making  it  static.Its a bad idea.
Because to synchronize its access you need class level lock. Class level
locks need to be carefully examined it can adversely effect the performance of 
your application.

May be your static shared resource can be converted to use any of the concurrent Data 
structures like ConcurrentHashMaP , ConcurrentLinkedQueue then you are good to go.

Comment: please do add comment on why you are downvoting?